# Loopback, AngularJS and validation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, loopbackjs, strongloop

I followed this tutorial to create a project with Loopback and AngularJs. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-angular

Now, I have an application with:

- HTML files (with Bootstrap)
- AngularJS controllers
- AngularJS service (generated with syntax lb-ng server/server.js client/js/services/lb-services.js)
- Model (located in ./common folder)
- MongoDB backend

The model "Device" is defined in ./common/models/device.js

```
module.exports = function(Device) {
};
```

And in ./common/models/device.json

```
{
  "name": "Device",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "category": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "initialDate": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "initialPrice": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "memory": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

In the "AddDeviceController", I have an initialization part with:

```
$scope.device = new DeviceToBuy({
  name: '',
  description: '',
  category: '',
  initialPrice: 0,
  memory: 8
  initialDate: Date.now()
});
```

And I am able to save the $scope.device when executing the following method:

```
  $scope.save = function() {
     Device.create($scope.device)
      .$promise
      .then(function() {
        console.log("saved");
        $scope.back(); // goto previous page
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  }
```

When everything is valid, the model is saved in the backend.  If something is not valid in the $scope.device, I receive an error from my backend.  So everything is working fine.

Now, I would like to use the model to perform client-side validation before sending my model to the backend and put some "error-class" on the bootstrap controls.

I tried something in the $scope.save function before sending to the backend:

```
if ($scope.device.isValid()) {
  console.log("IsValid");
} else {
  console.log("Not Valid");
}
```

But I get an exception "undefined is not a function" --> isValid() doesn't exist. 
And I cannot find any example on how to execute this client-side validation.

Comment: WHat is `isValid()` function? where do you set it?

Comment: Here I found a documentation telling the model (Device) is inheriting some features http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Basic+model+object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoopBack models are unopinionated and therefore do not provide client side validation out-of-box. You should use Angular validation mechanisms before calling $save.

Comment: And is it possible to use the "./common/model/device.json" for the Angular validation?

Comment: Not without some work - angular validation is done using attributes on form input elements. See https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation. If you wanted to you *could* write an HTML generator that uses the model.json file(s) and outputs the corresponding validation rules in adherence to the angular input directive.

Comment: But come to think of it - `slc arc` provides this for adding data for dev admins, so it would be hypothetically possible to dig into the arc source code and repurpose it for public consumption.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I will check how I can solve this problem with limited code